# Error Maven this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Tags: java, maven, jar

Estoy compilando un proyecto Maven, y a la hora hacer Maven Install me sale el siguiente error:

Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.0-M5:repackage failed: Unable to load the mojo 'repackage' in the plugin 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.0-M5' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: org/springframework/boot/maven/RepackageMojo has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

En Java me sale la versión 1.8_0_171 y en las variables de entorno la versión 1.8_0_121

¿Es posible que sea por esto o necesito intalar una versión de java mayor?

Comment: *`this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0`* El mensaje te está diciendo que tu actual versión de Java sólo admite hasta la versión 52.0 de esa librería y tú tienes instalada la versión 61.0. Entonces, tienes dos opciones: o haces un upgrade de tu versión de Java, o haces un downgrade de tu librería.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una tabla donde se indican las versiones, tu tienes la versión 8 (mayor version 52):

| Java SE version | Major version |
| --- | --- |
| 1.0.2 | 45 |
| 1.1 | 45 (Not a typo, same version) |
| 1.2 | 46 |
| 1.3 | 47 |
| 1.4 | 48 |
| 5.0 | 49 |
| 6 | 50 |
| 7 | 51 |
| 8 | 52 |
| 9 | 53 |
| 10 | 54 |
| 11 | 55 |
| 12 | 56 |
| 13 | 57 |
| 14 | 58 |
| 15 | 59 |
| 16 | 60 |

Es correcto lo que mencionas, debes instalar una versión de java mayor a 8.